# How to change mysql timezone with phpmyadmin on AppFog

Tags: php, mysql, appfog

My app is on appfog (AWS asia). I want to change default timezone to get correct time when using DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP.
I tried

```
 SET GLOBAL time_zone = "Asia/Calcutta";
```

But It gives error

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: Access has been denied.  Your MySQL user cannot make changes to the `GLOBAL` settings of the MySQL server - only those with the `SUPER` privilege can make such changes.  If the server has been misconfigured, you will need someone with the appropriate access level to fix it.

Comment: Well, actually the error is self explanatory. Do you have the credentials to do that?

Comment: No I don't. Actually Expecting some appfog sepcific answer. I wanna know if it is possible.

Comment: yes, it's possible... you just need the rights to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In the AppFog infrastructure, many users, in many timezones, all share the same database engine. Because of this, individual users are not allowed to change the global timezone setting for all the different databases running on a given server.

However, if you read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html you will see that the time zone can be changed for a given connection with `SET time_zone = <timezone>`, so if you wrap your mysql statements in that, you will have less timezone conversion logic to do.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to save everything in UTC/GMT time and then add time zone difference while displaying the time?

This way your time data will remain correct even if there is some change in server timezone while moving to some other service.